# Clarification on the method used to prove the existence of $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: proof-explanation

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x^2\leq{2}\}$ with $\sup A=\alpha$.

When proving that the $\sqrt{2}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ using the method of contradiction, do we show that a contradiction arises for the case $\alpha^2 \lt{2}$ by negating condition $1$ of the definition for least upper bound, and a contradiction for the case $\alpha^2 \gt{2}$ by negating condition $2$? leading to the conclusion that $\alpha^2={2}$ is the only possibility?

**Definition**: 
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $\alpha$ to be the *least upper bound* for $A$ if and only if the following two conditions are satisfied.

1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound for $A$; and
2. for all upper bounds $\alpha'$ for $A$, we have that $\alpha \leq{\alpha'}$

Comment: What are condition 1 and condition 2?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited to include the definition containing the conditions.

Comment: Then, yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos